# Webpack Error in routes.js : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/views/Home' in route.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack-2

I am trying run Webpack but Webpack can't resolve my Vue component [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l99M.png)

I try `import Home from './views/Home';`  But it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import('./views/Home.vue')
  }
]
```

Comment: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../views/Home.vue' in js`

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, try with ./ (not ../)

Comment: `ERROR in ./resources/js/views/Home.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div class="container">
|         <div class="row">

webpack compiled with 1 error`